# How do I constantly change the background the colour?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am working on a Loop, with Tkinter and was wondering how I could change to code so that I could change the background every second. In this code should work but whenever I run the program it crashes!

I have gotten a professional to look at it but still, we were not able to figure out why this code wasn't working. Also when you get rid of the `while True:` part it only configures the background to the last color.

```
from Tkinter import *
import time

root = Tk()

root.geometry("500x500+200+200")
root.title("Epilepsy Giver")
root.resizable(width = FALSE, height = FALSE)

def wait():
    time.sleep(1)

def start():
    while True:
        wait()
        root.configure(background='red')
        wait()
        root.configure(background='orange')
        wait()
        root.configure(background='yellow')
        wait()
        root.configure(background='green')
        wait()
        root.configure(background='blue')
        wait()
        root.configure(background='purple')
        wait()
        root.configure(background='violet')

startButton = Button(root,text="START",command=start)
startButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of a generator and `root.after()` to do your task:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.geometry("500x500+200+200")
root.title("Epilepsy Giver")
root.resizable(width = FALSE, height = FALSE)

def get_colour():
    colours = ['red', 'orange', 'yellow', 'green', 'blue', 'purple', 'violet']
    while True:
        for c in colours:
            yield c
def start():
    root.configure(background=next(colour_getter)) # set the colour to the next colour generated
    root.after(1000, start) # run this function again after 1000ms

colour_getter = get_colour()
startButton = Button(root,text="START",command=start)
startButton.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Could you explain why the program actually runs? Surely a while True loop will cause the window to not respond? Is yield different?

Comment: @JoshuaNixon yield is much different- it makes a function not a function, but a generator. The big example of a common generator is `range()`, as that's a generator. Generators are iterable like lists and such, but are functions/coroutines that pause their execution until something asks for the `next()` thing (`for` loops do this implicitly when given a generator, otherwise you have to call `next` on the generator, as `start()` in this example does).

Comment: Although in theory, this code should work the `while True` component causes the program to freeze.

Comment: This is what I tried and still the program isn't working:

Comment: generators are different from a traditional while loop, generator "pause" the loop at every yield statement therefore the tkinter program does not freeze. You should never have a direct `while True` when using tkinter

Comment: Thanks for the help, now it's working. But I have decided to move away from Tkinter, especially for creating games. I am currently learning Pygame and already it's a lot more advanced and complex.

Comment: Yup, pygame has a lot of good tools to build simple and complex games, it’s a very easy to use and understand. Fun fact, hint hint, pygame uses tkinter as its backbone :p

Answer (score 0):

To futher clarify [abccd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6622817/abccd)'s answer, the issue with your code lies in using 
`time.sleep()` vs Tk's `after()`.

In your example, `sleep()` will freeze the program execution. Tk doesn't have time to redraw the window between the calls to to sleep,  so you're effectively seeing an infinite loop of `sleep()` commands. Hence the freezing/crashing.

`after()`, on the other hand will schedule your Tk application the way you need it to.

Comment: Tk's root isn't being handle by another thread.It's just a single thread. Also, the calls to configure aren't "skipped over". It's simply the case that tkinter isn't given an opportunity to redraw the window. The configure happens, you just can't see it.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification! I thought I had read somewhere that that was the case, but I should have double-checked it. Edited my answer.

Comment: I'd add that being in a separate `while` loop never gives the tkinter mainloop priority- it isn't necessarily the `sleep` that holds it, it's the fact that tkinter can't redraw (omitting the sleeps will still make the window not seem to update)

Comment: Tkinter really hates `while` loop, like I am learning Pygame and you can have multiple `while` loops without any issue.

Answer (score -1):

Early, to avoid strange errors with Tk I created all UI elements in one thread and start there loop which waits for incoming events. All interactive elements or activity from other threads puts "queries"/event to this queue, but real changing of elments happens in the thread where element was created. This was rule for Tcl/Tk (8.5, 8.6). Try such model. Please, see how it's done in this code - https://code.google.com/archive/p/pybase/downloads